# drawing image on end point of arc in Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I was trying to put image icon on end tip of an arc in canvas.Both at beginning and end point of an arc. But not able to do that.

My js code:

```
var coord=getPoint(x, y, radius,  endAngle);
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://dailydropcap.com/images/D-6.jpg';
context.drawImage(img, coord.x, coord.y,'20px','20px');
context.stroke();
```

My [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefun/xF3Sa/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the XY at any angle on your arc like this:

```
function xyOnArc(cx,cy,radius,radianAngle){
    var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(radianAngle);
    var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(radianAngle);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/C4Y3V/

[image]

Here's example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var cx=100;
    var cy=100;
    var radius=40;
    var startAngle=Math.PI/2;
    var endAngle=Math.PI*2;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,endAngle);
    ctx.stroke();

    var start=xyOnArc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle);
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.fillRect(start.x,start.y,20,20);

    var end=xyOnArc(cx,cy,radius,endAngle);
    ctx.fillStyle="green";
    ctx.fillRect(end.x,end.y,20,20);

    function xyOnArc(cx,cy,radius,radianAngle){
        var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(radianAngle);
        var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(radianAngle);
        return({x:x,y:y});
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Addition: how to give image time to load ]**

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    // img is now fully loaded
    // do your drawImage inside this onload function
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
}
img.src = 'http://dailydropcap.com/images/D-6.jpg';
```

Comment: My getPoint() function also giving same coordinates. Now I want to display image on that point. I used drawImage() function. But image is not displaying

Comment: Is there anything I have missed in drawImage functionality?

Comment: Yes, you must give your image time to load before you try to use it in drawImage. I posted and addition to my answer showing how to wait until the image loads before doing drawImage.  Also, the size arguments should be 20 -- not 20px.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle showing images drawn at both ends of an arc: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/C4Y3V/